# raw browser in mne package won't open - python

Tags: python

I am trying to plot my EEG data with men (to be able to visually see it), but for some reason, it closes the raw-browser before it even opens.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mne
raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf("test2070622_Recording_00_BT.edf")
raw.plot(duration=5, n_channels=12)`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I am using visual studio. This is what the terminal says:

> raw = mne.io.read_raw_edf("test2070622_Recording_00_BT.edf")
> Using matplotlib as 2D backend.
> Opening raw-browser...
> Closing raw-browser...
> Channels marked as bad:
> none

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

To solved, I had to move my code on a Jupyter file.

Best regard :)